# Apart from the Java application who created a UDP socket, who else can close it?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

We see `java.net.SocketException: socket closed` in our server logs (server listens on UDP port 1812). But we cannot see any trace of the server closing the underlying `DatagramSocket`. Here is the stack trace:

```
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketReceiveOrPeekData(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The question is that, apart from the application that created the socket, who else can close it?

(If it's relevant the server is running on Windows with Java 8.)

Comment: Nobody. You closed it yourself. Debug.